# How to implement split-complex numbers?

Tags: programming, algebraic-manipulation, algebra

For those who do not know, the split-complex numbers are an analogue to the complex numbers where J is defined such that $J^2=1$ but $J\ne\pm1$, so they are all of the form $a+bJ$.

By using TagSetDelayed, I tried to define the split-complex numbers as so:

```
J /: J^2 := 1
```

If I then type `J^2`, I get the output `1`.
However, if I type `J^3`, I just get the output `J^3`. I would like to instead get the output $J$, since $J^3=J^2J=1J=J$.
Is there a better way to implement this number system?

Comment: Might be easier to do this using 2x2 matrix representations.

Comment: Ummmm.... isn't $J = -1$?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify that $J\ne -1$ either, I've edited the question to fix that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
J /: Power[J, p_Integer?OddQ] := J
J /: Power[J, p_Integer?EvenQ] := 1


J^Range[-10, 10]
```

> {1, J, 1, J, 1, J, 1, J, 1, J, 1, J, 1, J, 1, J, 1, J, 1, J, 1}

Comment: This will not work with most functions. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can represent split-complex numbers as multivectors (geometric number, clifford number) with signature $(1, 0)$. I have a [paclet](https://github.com/sw1sh/GeometricAlgebra) for this:

```
PacletInstall["https://wolfr.am/OkONsyY2"]

<< GeometricAlgebra`

(* this is your split-complex number *)
h = Multivector[{a, b}, 1]

(* you can perform numeric operations with it *)
h^2
h^-1
MultivectorFunction[Exp, h] (* similar to MatrixFunction *)
```

Comment: See my much simpler answer.

Answer (score 1):

This way, add this line to the top of the notebook:

```
$Post = #/.J->{-1,1}/.{x_,y_}->(x+y)/2+J(y-x)/2&;
```

Use like this:

```
In:= Log[J]

Out:= (I Pi)/2 - (I Pi J)/2

In:= I^J

Out:= I J
```